# vb.net find occurrences of dot number dot

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, search, contains

Should be a real quick one this for those who are good with regex etc, I have some strings and I want to only extract those where it has a dot then a single number between 0-9 and finally another dot. As such:

```
string2.string = no good

string.1.string = match

strstr.9.strstr = match

str3.-3.str = no good
```

etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
\.\d\.
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/zC3iQ9/1

And the VB code:

```
Dim input = "string.1.string"
Dim pattern = "\.\d\."
Dim matches = Regex.Match(input, pattern).Success
```

Comment: Don't suppose you know what would need to be included if I wanted to have the number as any number as 123 or 1000 etc? I was thinking something like \.\d+$\. would do it

Comment: sorry sussed that one, its "\.\d+\."

Comment: Yes, that should do: https://regex101.com/r/zC3iQ9/2

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex, in VB.NET you have the simple [`Like`-operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx):

```
Dim matches = From str In strings
              Where str Like "*.#.*"
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, matches))
```

Comment: Both great answers, ty :)